# How to check-in the code in correct account after committing in wrong account of github?

Tags: git, github

I have made a commit in github. Then I realized that I am in the wrong account. I then closed the git shell and Changed the username and email. When I checked 'git status', it shows a notification that 'one item ready to push'. It does`t show any modification. When I make a 'git push'. The code was checked-in an old(wrong) account.

So If any one knows how to check-in the code in correct account after committing in github ?

I have the account details of the another account also. Is there any way to delete the check-in. ?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out myself. I used the following code. It works great.

> git rebase -i HEAD~2

Then I deleted the second line of commit.

> git push origin +master

The code is resettled. Then I make my new commit as usual.

Answer (score 1):

What changes you can or should make will depend on if this commit is visible to other users of the repository and how willing you are to rewrite your commit history based on that (in general you probably do not want to edit the history of any branch other users rely on).

If you want to change the author of a single commit you can use `git commit --amend --reset-author` (see [Change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git) and other questions for more detail).

If you want to remove a specific commit you can use `reset` or an interactive `rebase` to rollback and unstage or discard those changes. (See [How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-git-commit) and other similar questions.)